# Modern version of Start - All Programs - Startup

Tags: windows-10, boot

I have a script that launches via a certain program that I want to be run on startup (on login, really). I used to be able to tell people to do this by dragging it into Start → All Programs → Startup, but that isn't much of a thing anymore on Windows 10.

What is the *most user-friendly* way to schedule something (not a program, but a file or script) to open on login in the new Windows world?

Answer (score 2):

A similar idea to what you are doing, just a different location is all. *This solution also works for Windows 7 keep in mind too.*

**For a specific user**

1. Put the file or script you want to start here for a specific user:

   ```
   C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
   ```
2. Press Windows key + R and run the following:

   ```
   shell:startup
   ```

[image]

3. Place a shortcut for your program or script in this location.

[image]

Copy the file.

[image]

Paste a link to the location above.

[image]

It should look like this.

**For all users**

1. Put the file or script you want to start here for all users:

   ```
   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp
   ```
2. Press Windows key + R and run the following:

   ```
   shell:Common Startup
   ```
3. Place a shortcut for your program or script in this location. Reference instructions given under the specific user section of this answer.

Reference: http://tunecomp.net/add-app-to-startup/

Comment: Thanks. This is useful. I am disappointed there isn't a simpler way.

Comment: @AlanH.Not too bad... similar as before just with one more step. If it did help can you please mark this as the accepted answer? Glad I could help.

Comment: I see three steps now where there used to be one. Actually unless you own TuneComp, i don’t think it’s cool (or legal) that you just placed their entire answer, including screen shots, here as if it were your own work. That site says, “Copying of the site materials is prohibited,” which of course is the default for all original works under copyright law.

Comment: @AlanH I gave credit to them if you read the bottom of my answer and link only answers are against SU policy in case the link ever moves or disappears. Sorry for helping you then if you feel that against what I posted. Also the images do not have a copyright on them just because a website has some screen shots of windows. The actual procedure does not have a copyright either so not really sure what you are talking about.

Comment: To be fair you did paraphrase the procedure although I think it got confused on the way. And while screen shots of windows are not the biggest deal, they are in fact the copyright of whoever created them. Giving credit is good but it doesn’t give you license, you know? I’m not trying to start sh-t, just letting you know :)